# Extract all twitter usernames using Powershell

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell, twitter

I want to parse a string and return an array (list) containing the people mentioned in that tweet. Twitter usernames all begin with @.

How can I extract ALL twitter usernames in a string using Powershell?

```
$text = @"
    text text text 
    @twitter text text text @facebook 
    text text text @linkedin text text text 
        Hello <a href="http://twitter.com/twitter">@twitter</a> and <a href="http://twitter.com/facebook">@facebook</a> @kiquenet
"@
```

I would get:

```
@twitter 
@facebook 
@linkedin 
@kiquenet
```

Answer (score 1):

Using V3:

```
$text = @"
    text text text 
    @twitter text text text @facebook 
    text text text @linkedin text text text 
        Hello <a href="http://twitter.com/twitter">@twitter</a> and <a href="http://twitter.com/facebook">@facebook</a> @kiquenet
"@

$regex = [regex]'\s@[^@ ]+\s?'

$regex.matches($text).groups.value

 @twitter 
 @facebook 
 @linkedin 
 @kiquenet
```

Answer (score 0):

If such **@username** contains letters only `[a-zA-Z]` and before/after such **@username** is nothing or space, comma or dot `[\s,.]` and/or tag characters (greater-than signs `>`, less-than sign `<`) then you should use regex pattern:

```
(?:(?<=[\s,.>])|^)@[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?=[\s,.<])|$)
```

If some other characters are allowed, then the pattern has to be adjusted, but this example should be enough helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Split method:

```
$text.split() -like "@*"
```

With regex:

```
[regex]::matches($text,'@[^\s|<]+') | foreach {$_.value} | sort -unique
```